# can't link css file in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to django and I am trying to link css file to a template.

1. I am using developement server
2. In my project in settings.py I have app 'django.contrib.staticfiles'
3. In my `project/app` folder I have `static` folder and inside `file.css`
4. In `index.html` file (inside `project/app/templates/app`) I tried to use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/file.css" />` and also tried it with `STATIC_URL`.

Unfortunately variable STAIC_URL (and MEDIA_URL) are empty strings so the result url is `/file.css`.

Can any1 help me? I know where are some STATIC_URL variables in settings.py but StaticFinder should find the file autmaticaly in app/static , shouldnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use RequestContext, or the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut, which ensures that context processors are run and the variables are added to your template.

Comment: perfect, thanks! One more question - will it work on the non-developement server?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "work". As the documentation explains, on the production server you need to set up your own configuration to serve the static files. Once you've done that, and set STATIC_URL appropriately, the above will work.

Comment: This is stupid - so when I make my own app and give the app to someone then if he wants to use it he has to add some static path to static files in his project settings.py??

Comment: I don't understand. If someone's running their own Django site, then yes of course they need to set up something to serve static files for that site. Nothing to do with reusing an app from a different project: all apps in a project will use the same static setup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Django doc page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) with all the required information.

You might have forgotten to set `STATIC_ROOT`, `STATIC_URL` in your `setting.py` and then run the command `./manage.py collectstatic` which will collect all the static files from all apps in the project static directory.